# Index was outside the bounds of the array C# in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I input my QuaterDisplay as dummy data, but I get the error as below:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Code:

```
private string GetQuarterDisplay(DateTime dateKey)
{
    return ((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"
            + dateKey + "'"))[0].QuarterDisplay; //error occur here
}

internal void PropagateModelStartQuarter() 
{
    object[] args = new object[0];
    m_privateObject.Invoke("PropagateModelStartQuarter", new System.Type[0], args);
}
```

Comment: So what's your question, and clean up your code please, it looks like it's been through war

Comment: It's giving you that error because you're trying to access a index in your array that isn't there. If you had a length of 5 indexes, `[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]` and tried to access `[5]` then this would give you the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`. Make sure there is actually data in your `AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[]` array

Comment: what is `mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"dateKey"'"))`? Does it have any data in it?

Comment: You may want to use LINQ: `return mAvailabilityDS.Time.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateKey == dateKey)`

Comment: there are number of row in Time table with DateKey, e.g.12/31/2006 12:00:00 AM 4/1/2007 12:00:00 AM 7/1/2007 12:00:00 AM 9/30/2007 12:00:00 AM 12/30/2007 12:00:00 AM 3/30/2008 12:00:00 AM 6/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 9/28/2008 12:00:00 AM 12/28/2008 12:00:00 AM 3/29/2009 12:00:00 AM 3/29/2009 12:00:00 AM

Comment: column of QuarterDisplay data:Q1 2007
Q2 2007
Q3 2007
Q4 2007
Q1 2008
Q2 2008
Q3 2008
Q4 2008
Q1 2009
Q2 2009
Q2 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is the line in error:

```
((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"
        + dateKey + "'"))[0]
```

I guess there is no item on that time stamp, resulting in an empty array. If you try to access the first item in an empty array, that is the error you get.

If you use LINQ, you could use `FirstOrDefault`, which will not fail when there is no item. Instead, it will return the default value. In this case `null`:

```
var availability = ((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"
        + dateKey + "'")).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then:

```
if (availability != null)
{
    return availability.QuarterDisplay;
}
else
{
    // return a default value, or throw an exception
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I get the error at FirstOrDefault , Error 2 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You should include `using System.Linq;` on top of your code file.

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is no row in `mAvailabilityDS` table `Time` with specified `DateKey` string representation.

I would replace this with strongly typed LINQ solution:

```
private string GetQuarterDisplay(DateTime dateKey)
{
    return ((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select()
        .Where(x => x.DateKey == dateKey)
        .Select(x => x.QuarterDisplay)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**EDIT**

The main problem is that you are searching your rows by string representation of date/time object which is dependant on the current culture used.

This string representation does not match standard ISO format datetime (like 2009-11-03 00:00:00)  that is used in DataTable internals to filter values.

If you really want to use not-strongly-typed approach, convert datet/time object to string using invariant culture.

```
private string GetQuarterDisplay(DateTime dateKey)
{
    return ((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"
            + dateKey.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + "'"))[0].QuarterDisplay;
}
```

Comment: there are number of row in Time table with DateKey, e.g.12/31/2006 12:00:00 AM
4/1/2007 12:00:00 AM
7/1/2007 12:00:00 AM
9/30/2007 12:00:00 AM
12/30/2007 12:00:00 AM
3/30/2008 12:00:00 AM
6/29/2008 12:00:00 AM
9/28/2008 12:00:00 AM
12/28/2008 12:00:00 AM
3/29/2009 12:00:00 AM
3/29/2009 12:00:00 AM

Comment: So... What is your point? @nodisplay. Did you query those exact times?

Comment: column of QuarterDisplay data:Q1 2007 Q2 2007 Q3 2007 Q4 2007 Q1 2008 Q2 2008 Q3 2008 Q4 2008 Q1 2009 Q2 2009 Q2 2009

Comment: I get the error "Error 2 'Intel.ATMSS.MetricSystem.DataObject.AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Intel.ATMSS.MetricSystem.DataObject.AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  at LINE (.Where(x=>x.DateKey == dateKey))

Comment: You need to add a `using System.Linq;` directive in the file.

Comment: there is an error in "DateTimeFormatInfo", sorry I am first time user.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check for null?

```
private string GetQuarterDisplay(DateTime dateKey)
{
    var availabilityDS = (AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS
    if(availabilityDS != null) 
    {
        var time = availabilityDS.Time;
        if(time != null) 
        {
            var elements = availabilityDS.Select('"+ dateKey + "'");
            if(elements.Any()) 
            {
                return elements[0].QuarterDisplay;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the Select class returns an item. If it's an empty array then you are indexing into an empty array. Use something like:

```
private string GetQuarterDisplay(DateTime dateKey)
{
    var times =((AvailabilityDS.IntelTimeRow[])mAvailabilityDS.Time.Select("DateKey = '"
        + dateKey + "'"));

    if (times.Length > 0)
    {
        return times[0].QuarterDisplay; 
    }

    return null; // Or whatever
}
```

Alternatively use if (!times.Any())...

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Select` didn't return any rows, therefore you get the mentioned exception if you try to access a non-existing row.

You may want to use LINQ instead which makes it much more readable:

```
var timeRow = mAvailabilityDS.Time.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateKey == dateKey);
if(timeRow != null)
    return timeRow.QuarterDisplay;
else
    return null;
```

Maybe you don't find any rows because there is a time portion that you want to ignore. Then you can use the `Date` property of `DateTime`:

```
var timeRow = mAvailabilityDS.Time.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateKey.Date == dateKey.Date);
```